# "Error" being displayed many times when using Minicom after connecting ESP8266 to Raspberry Pi 2 Model B

Tags: pi-2, raspbian-jessie

I am using RPi2 Model B with Raspbian Jessie.

I have connected an ESP8266 to Pi. Google says that I have to disable kernel debug messages and serial console login to use the serial port of RPi. I have disabled the kernel from using the serial port. Now no debug messages appear while powering on the Pi.

Following this [link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=123081) i have done

```
sudo systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service
sudo systemctl disable serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service
```

to disable serial console login.

But when I try to communicate to ESP8266 using AT commands through minicom, I get a screen filled with "ERROR" and sometimes "Login Incorrect" and "5 Incorrect login attempts" (The error wordings are not exact)

How to rectify this? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I've edited the last paragraph out of your question since it invites general discussion about usage of the ESP8266, and we actually are *not* a discussion forum, we're a *Q&A* site; sometimes new users find this confusing.  You should take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) for further explanation, it is about 2-3 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Following this link i have done

That link is outdated.  To disable the serial console and login on current versions of Raspbian, all you have to do is edit `/boot/cmdline.txt` and remove:

```
console=serial0,115200
```

It may read `ttyAMA0` instead of `serial0`, but the way to identify an entry for a serial console is the baud rate (`115200`) after a comma.  **Do not** remove the other console entry, which should be `console=tty1`.

The current init system will automatically start a login on any serial console used by the kernel, so if you disable that, nothing further has to be done.

Beware that file (`cmdline.txt`) must remain *all one line*.  You will need to reboot after editing it.

Comment: I made a clean install of Raspbian Jessie and I did what you mentioned. If I send an AT command nothing is returned. Do you have any links which tells how to use ESP8266 with RPi 2 With Jessie?

Comment: No, I've never used one; I left another comment on your question about this.  The basic idea is to ask one focused question at a time.  An advantage of this is, e.g., if you had asked something  more opened ended and far ranging, I would not have bothered to answer (because I've never used an ESP8266) -- and perhaps no one else would have either, because it then becomes more esoteric.  As is, it sounds like this at least solved your initial problem with the login console on the serial line.

Comment: So: Now you are over that hurdle, please feel free to ask a *separate* question focused on use of the ESP8266!  The more details you can include about 1) What you've actually tried, 2) What you expected to happen, and 3) What actually happened, the better your chances of getting decent advice.